# Insert hyperlink in jspdf

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have this JavaScript code that allows me to generate a table in a PDF file using the JSPDF library. In my table, I have URLs and I would like to be able to add a clickable link for each row of the PDF table.

```
var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4');
doc.autoTable({
        startY: 40,
     
        head: [["Field1","Field2","Field3", "Field4","Field5","Field6","Field7"]],
        
        body: my_array,
    });
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the external link URL in the desired field, its similar to HTML linking via href=.

So here using the Autotable web demo file in Acrobat, clicking on https://www.google.com will attempt to hyperlink via the browser.
It will be the same in a browser the PDF will try to open by defaults Google in the same frame, but there the security blocker will not normally be triggered.

[image]

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for this response, I have already tried it. However, I am looking for a method to replace the URL with a custom name that is clickable.

I tried using =hyperlink(URL, "Click") to replace my URL with "Click", but in the code, it treats the semicolon as a line break and I end up with "Click" on a new line.

Do you have any ideas to help me add this functionality to my report?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to add a link to a text that lm try on my project

doc.textWithLink('Link', 100, 35, { url: this.url });

it will create an element with Link text that redirects to this.url

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem and after a lot of research I solve this by custom adding the link on the place of each cell of autotable:

```
const pdf = new jsPDF({
          orientation: "landscape",
        });
        pdf.addImage(logo, 'PNG', 15, 5, 100, 30);
        pdf.text('Webtest Report', 15, 50);
        let columns = [['S.No', 'Name', 'Description', 'Type', 'Start Time', 'End Time', 'Duration', 'Status', 'Image']]
        let data = response.data.map(test => [
          test.s_no,
          test.name,
          test.description,
          test.type,
          test.start_time,
          test.end_time,
          test.duration,
          test.status,
          // 'image'
        ]);
        pdf.autoTable({
          startY: 60,
          head: columns,
          body: data,
          columnStyles: { 5: { cellWidth: 30 } },
          didDrawCell: (data) => {
            if (data.column.dataKey === 8 && data.cell.section === "body") {
              const x = data.cell.x;
              const y = data.cell.y + 5;
              pdf.textWithLink('Click here', x, y, { url: 'path to your image url' });
            }
          }})
         
        // Save the PDF 
        pdf.save('webtest-report.pdf');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXXvo.png)